# A simple way to update PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, version

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 with PHP 5.3.3 and would like to update to PHP 5.3.5. Is there a simple way to update the PHP version to 5.3.5? Something like `apt-get install php5=5.3.5`?

Best regards,
Jambo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With official Ubuntu packages this is not possible for the time being, as the latest packaged version is 5.3.3. This also holds true for natty (current development release, that'll become 11.04), so the options are either to compile from source or try your luck with the aforementioned Debian package.

Comment: Hmm. Looks like I have to install it from source. Sad to hear 5.3.3 will be in 11.04. Thans @vehnae and @Sebastian P.

Comment: It's not said that 11.04 will ship with 5.3.3, it's just the current situation in the package repository.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get the following Debian package to work: http://www.dotdeb.org/2011/01/11/php-5-3-5-now-for-squeeze/

Answer (score 0):

I you want to upgrade Ubuntu 10.04 LTS to PHP 5.3.10, this is how I have done it:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge php*  
sudo apt-get autoremove  
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brianmercer/php5  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cli php5-cgi php5-mysql php5-gd  
sudo service apache2 restart  
sudo pecl uninstall apc  
sudo pecl install apc
```

Thanks to Brian Mercer for his PPA for php5.